# How to send the selected values from list box using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to send the multiple selected data from list box using ajax in mvc. I get the selected data. I dont know how to send the data ajax to controller. My code is below:

```
var Students= [];

            var x = document.getElementById("ListBox");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
                if (x.options[i].selected == true) {
                    Students.push(x.options[i].text)
                }
            }


 $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id:studenid, class: class,  Students: Students},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                }
            }); // id:studenid, class:classs values are send it properly how to add the students?
```

Comment: I'm guessing replacing `data: { User: Users },` with `data: { Students: Students },` would be a good start. Then you figure out how to catch that on the server, but first you have to actually send it somewhere with a valid URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `url:''` field is empty. You need to add some URL there for which you have written the server side code which is ready to accept data.

And, of course, I'm guessing that you wish to send `data:{Student:Students}` instead of `data:{User:Users}`. Preferably `data:{Student:Students}`

Comment: JSON.parse(Students) it tells invalid char

Comment: data:{Student:Students} i am using already this type but not passing to contoller

Answer (score 0):

//Send width param name

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
      data: { paramName: Students},
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {

      }
    });



  //Get value
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetValue(string paramName)
      {

      }
```

In The Generic Handler

```
//Send
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:'/MyHandler.ashx?students=Students,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(msg) {

          }
        });

//Get

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string students= (string)context.Request["students"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Students= [];

            var x = document.getElementById("ListBox");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
                if (x.options[i].selected == true) {
                    Students.push(x.options[i].text)
                }
            }
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {StudentList:Students},
   url: "index.aspx",
   success: function(msg){
     alert(msg);
   }
});
```

Comment: i need to pass this value to controller (mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm the data type of "Students" object you are passign to controller.

Try to use Array data type,

```
Public ActionResult SendData(string id, string class,Array  Students)
{

}
```

If it is not working then convert Javascript array to string array with delimeter(,) and use below

```
Public ActionResult SendData(string id, string class,string Students)
{

}
```

This will help you. 
Thanks.